# UIImagePickerController spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

i am trying to use UIImagepickerController to pick an image from photos.
I am using the function below in my gameScene class
(this is for importing images into a game)

But I get the error  "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
on this line

```
self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
```

the function is below. I am not sure how to fix it and have searched for an answer without much luck, so any help would be great.

```
   func getPhotoFromSource(source:UIImagePickerControllerSourceType ){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(source)
    {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = source
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        if (source == .camera){
            imagePicker.cameraDevice = .front
        }
        let vc:UIViewController =   self.view!.window!.rootViewController!  //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

        vc.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
let vc:UIViewController =   self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
```

, use optional chaining and try

```
guard let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController else {
    print("something went wrong")
}
```

Seeing how it's either your view or your window or your `rootViewController` that's not there when you try to force unwrap, if you run the code above your code will just run the print statement above.

Can you share your code for setting up your `viewController`?

Comment: `import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
            
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }`

Comment: i am not sure how to format the code in a comment, but the above is the gameViewController file code.  Ive opened a standard new Xcode game project and the only code in it so far is the image picker code to test it.

Comment: @carl umm you know you can edit your original post and add more stuff in there, right? :P

Comment: thanks, your guard code worked for opening up the picker,